# A problem with showing that some subspace is a hyperplane

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be a vector space over $K$ and $V\neq X$ be its linear subspace such that for each $y\in X\setminus V$ we have $\{v+ay: v\in V, a\in K\}=X$.

How to show that for each linear subspace $V'$ such that $V\subset V' \subset X$ we have either $V'=V$ or $V'=X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V = V'$ then you are done.

If $V \neq V'$ then there is a $y \in V' \setminus V$ and you know by assumption that $\{v + ay : v \in V, a \in K\} = X$.

Now if $u \in X$ then you from this you know that there exist $v \in V$ and $a \in K$ such that $u = v + ay$. Since $V \subseteq V'$ this also means $v \in V'$. Since $y \in V'$ also $ay\in V'$ because $V'$ is a linear subspace. For the same reason $u = v + ay \in V'$. Hence $u \in V'$. So you have shown $X \subseteq V'$ which together with $V' \subseteq X$ gives $X = V'$.